# Maximum cardinality disjoint cycle cover in undirected graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, optimization, time-complexity

I call a maximum cardinality disjoint cycle cover of a graph a vertex-disjoint cycle cover containing the maximum possible number of cycles in the graph. What is known about the complexity of this problem in general and in restricted graph classes (e.g., $k$-regular)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if there is a disjoint triangle cover of $G$ then this would be the cycle cover  of maximum cardinality. And it is NP-hard to determine if there is a disjoint triangle cover.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think to look for literature on *triangle* covers. What are some good references on this problem?

Comment: @delete000 there is a lot, so it really depends on what direction you want to go into ... FPT exact algorithms, approximation algorithms, heuristics, etc. I don't know if there are results on $k$-regular graphs, and I'm not yet convinced it remains hard on $k$-regular graphs.